# Andengine eglSwapBuffers failed

Tags: android, opengl-es, andengine

I know this question has been asked before but there's still no answer, so here is the problem:
I am receiving the following exceptions in my game:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: eglSwapBuffers failed: EGL_SUCCESS
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.throwEglException(GLSurfaceView.java:1085)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.swap(GLSurfaceView.java:1043)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1369)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1123)
```

and

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: eglSwapBuffers failed: EGL_BAD_ALLOC
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.throwEglException(GLSurfaceView.java:1082)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.swap(GLSurfaceView.java:1040)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1338)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1121)
```

This happens only on some devices, I haven't been able to reproduce it on my devices. I know many have reported this problem. Has anyone found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this bug can be resolved by decreasing texture size to 1024x1024.